# X, Y of mouse click in EventClick callback

Tags: fullcalendar

In FullCalendar, how can I get the position of mouse click (x,y) in eventClick callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
  alert(jsEvent.pageX); //X coordinate
  alert(jsEvent.pageY); //Y coordinate
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, that helped. What if I want to get the same for Select: call back (when a time slot is clicked)

Comment: Check the documentation for FullCalendar. The Select callback has jsEvent too - so it carries the same properties.
Note: this site is much more helpful if you do your research first!

Comment: I always do that. I don't know what happened to me that I directly created the thread here without even seeing the documentation. Really Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void eventClick(Event e){
        int x,y;

        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
    }
```

This is assuming that your working with java.

Comment: I asked in context of FullCalendar